# What's the difference between '>' and '>>'?

Tags: unix, command, pipe

What's the difference between

```
cat int.txt > out.txt
```

and

```
cat int.txt >> out.txt
```

Does the `>>` do anything differently from `>`?

Comment: Downvoters, are you downvoting because this could have easily been googled, or another reason?

Comment: Is this also true of (Windows) batch files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` is to re-direct standard output to the file and overwrite it if the file exists.

`>>` is to append standard output to the file if it exists

Some more options:

http://www.mathinfo.u-picardie.fr/asch/f/MeCS/courseware/users/help/general/unix/redirection.html

Answer (score 5):

The `>` will overwrite `out.txt` if it already exists. The `>>` will simply append to `out.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

`>` overwrites to the file. `>>` appends to the file.

Answer (score 2):

`>>`  will append to out.txt if it exists

`>`  will overwrite out.txt if it exists

Answer (score 1):

```
cat int.txt > out.txt
```

This has written the contents of int.txt to out.txt and overwritten anything that was in that file (out.txt) if it already existed.

```
cat int.txt >> out.txt
```

This has appended int.txt to the end of out.txt if it existed or simply created it if it didn't, and copied int.txt into it.